# Changing data that arrives to a stored procedure from int to string. How to split delimited data as a set of integers and perform a filter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that takes in 4 variables and filters data based on it. One of the variable changed from int to varchar. Now, the varchar must do the filter that int did.

tried using status as varchar and using split function and received error.

Existing code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROCNAME]
@IDorder as bigint,
@countofresult int = 5
@Ordering INTEGER,
@Status varchar = '1,2', -- this was accepting one int but now accepts a varchar
as
begin
select top (@countofresult) * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.orderstatus=table2.orderstatusprocess
where 
fkl_id = @IDorder
and 
table1.statusID=@status
table1.statusID in (select data from split(@Status,',')) or (@Status is null))  
order by
case when @Ordering = 0 then priceVal end asc 
case when @ordering =1 then priceVal end desc
end
```

This works when status is null but doesn't when the status is a string. Am I using the split wrong ? Or does select data work different when changed type ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server